# Number of ternary sequences with given length

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to determine what is the number of all ternary sequences of the length 15, such that the sum of all digits in the sequence is odd and the digit 2 appears at most three times.

My first question is...**Can for example 000 or 111 be a ternary sequence?**

I figured that the number 1 has to appear odd-number of times (that will be half of all possible binary sequences) and then i will multiply it by all the posibilities of placing the numbers two. So for number 2 appearing twice it would be $
(2^{13}/2)*\binom{15}{2}\,
$.
Is my approach okay or did I miss something?

Comment: A ternary sequence is one composed of $0, 1,2$ so $000$ and $111$ both qualify.  There are $3^4=81$ four digit ternary sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine.  You need to add in the possibilities with $1$ or $0$ twos.